# function_clause error in Couchdb 1.1.0 after updating from 1.0.1

Tags: javascript, erlang, couchdb, mochiweb

I have errors when updating document in Couchdb 1.1.0 after updating it from 1.0.1
Response looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
  [error] => unknown_error
  [reason] => function_clause
)
```

When i was using 1.0.1 everything was ok.
There's something in "breaking changes" section regarding update from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0

> Document id's are now validated during PUT. This means that some PUT requests will fail that previously succeeded.

But i cant figure it out what that means in my case.

Comment: i forgot to mention: we have 40-character-length IDs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is pretty strange.
http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/oW6DzpeTL2Ybm1QHXsuq

So if you get the same error after updating your CouchDB server to 1.1.0, you have to remove your *.beam files from $INSTALL_DIR/bin. In my case, i had to manually remove files from /opt/couchdb/bin

Comment: one more: new couchdb views can't change documents. so if you could write before **emit(doc.array.pop(), null)**, now you should write **emit(doc.array[doc.array.length - 1], null)**

Answer (score 0):

This helped in my case:

I was upgrading vom 1.0.1 to 1.1.0 from source.
Before making 'make install' I had to delete the previous version in '/usr/local/lib/couchdb' (or rename it to '/usr/local/lib/couchdb-old').

This was on Debian Lenny.